# Question for DE SERMONE COTIDIANO

Tags: grammar-identification

I am reading the adaptation of *De Sermone Cotidiano* in *Lingua Latina: Sermones Romani*.

In the *Discipulus (II)* section, there is the sentence:

> Inter haec iussū magistrī surgunt pusillī ad elementa, et syllabās dīnumerāvit eīs ūnus dē māiōribus.

with notes:

[image]

So, what does ***surgunt ad elementa*** (rise to letters?) mean?

> Among these the young boys rise *to letters* by the teacher's order, and one of the older ones enumerated syllables to them.

Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be elliptic for two things:

- ***singulī** pusillī ad **singula** elementa,* i.e. "one by one in response to", or
- *ad elementa **recitanda*** "for reciting the letters", meaning everyone had to stand up and be prepared to repeat/recite them.

The latter seems more probable as a school practice to me as well as to the author of [this commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=PblaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA118) (E. Dickey). If the former was intended, one would expect at least the first *singulī.*